# JWT error with placement of jwt.sign code

Tags: node.js, authentication, jwt

I'm working on creating a authentication system and am trying to figure out how to use JWT. I'm using Node, express, passport and MYSQL. I tried creating the "var token" after the db.sync() method but that would only throw a error but then it works if i put the "var token" before db.sync() why is this? And should i do it this way? Thanks in advance!

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

var config = require('../config'),
    db = require('../services/database'),
    User = require('../models/user'),
    Organisation = require('../models/organisation'),
    Event = require('../models/event');

// The authentication controller.
var AuthController = {};

// Register a user.
AuthController.signUp = function(req, res) {
    if(!req.body.username || !req.body.password || !req.body.email) {
        res.json({ message: 'Please provide a username and a password.' });
    } else {
      var token = jwt.sign({ username: req.body.username }, config.keys.secret, { expiresIn: '30m' });  
        db.sync().then(function() {

            var newUser = {
                username: req.body.username,
                password: req.body.password,
                email: req.body.email,
                temporarytoken: token
            };
            console.log(newUser.temporarytoken);
            return User.create(newUser).then(function() {
                res.status(201).json({ message: 'Account created!' });
            });
        }).catch(function(error) {
            res.status(403).json({ message: 'Username already exists!' });
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your error message like?

Also, are you seeing errors if you do this code?

```
        db.sync().then(function() {
            var token = jwt.sign({ username: req.body.username }, config.keys.secret, { expiresIn: '30m' }); 

            var newUser = {
                username: req.body.username,
                password: req.body.password,
                email: req.body.email,
                temporarytoken: token
            };
            console.log(newUser.temporarytoken);
            return User.create(newUser).then(function() {
                res.status(201).json({ message: 'Account created!' });
            });
```

P.S. Why are you saving the token to the DB? You should send the jwt to the client and the client will save it to a local storage or cookie. That is the whole point of jwt.